# How to prevent listview to scroll automatically when write in edittext?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I face very strange issue in Samsung Galaxy Tab 10 Inch. I have one listview and in that i add edittext dynamically.

So suppose i add 20 edittext in listview and then try to write in any edittext, so at that time keyboad pop up and listview scroll to first position and i am not able to see what i write into edittext.

EditText hides behind the keyboard, can any one face this same issue?

Comment: It is a common problem with android, when you add element with focus on List. When I did that I override onToutch method, create new textwatcher to save cursor position, add dumy element resize a list to display chosen position. To save your nerves do not add editText in List.

Comment: chirag, this is the default behaviour of most devices. so it would be good to leave it like that.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your valuable suggestion, but @Hitesh Jain i am not leave it as it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a fake textview below the edittext may solve your problem...